# Multiple solutions from NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have a list of polynomial equations which I can solve using `NSolve`. However, it gives me a large number of similar solutions. The solutions are largely identical except for numerical error. The solution time is also far longer than I would like. Can we find a way of not calculating nearly identical solutions?

The unknowns and the equations are (sorry for the length and Greek)

```
uk = {A[0], A[1], B[1], A[2], B[2], A[3], B[3]};
eqns = {\[Omega]0^2 A[0] + \[Beta] A[0]^3 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[1]^2 + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[2]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[3]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[1]^2 - 3/4 \[Beta] A[2] B[1]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[1] B[2] - 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[1] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[2]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[2] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -F - \[Omega]^2 A[1] + \[Omega]0^2 A[1] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 A[1] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^3 + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] A[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2]^2 + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] A[3] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[3]^2 + 
     2 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 B[1] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[1] B[1]^2 - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[3] B[1]^2 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] B[1] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[2]^2 - 3/4 \[Beta] A[3] B[2]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[1] B[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0] B[2] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[2] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -2 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 A[1] - \[Omega]^2 B[
       1] + \[Omega]0^2 B[1] + 3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 B[1] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[1] - 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] B[1] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[1] - 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[3] B[1] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[3]^2 B[1] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[1]^3 + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[2] - 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[3] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] A[3] B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[1] B[2]^2 + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] B[3] - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[3] - 3/4 \[Beta] B[1]^2 B[3] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] B[2]^2 B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[1] B[3]^2 == 0, 
   3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[1]^2 - 4 \[Omega]^2 A[2] + \[Omega]0^2 A[2] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 A[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[2] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^3 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] A[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] A[3]^2 - 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[1]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1]^2 + 
     4 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[1] B[2] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2] B[2]^2 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] B[1] B[3] - 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[2] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -4 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 A[2] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[1] - 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[3] B[1] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] A[3] B[1] - 
     4 \[Omega]^2 B[2] + \[Omega]0^2 B[2] + 3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[2] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[2] - 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[3] B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3]^2 B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] B[1]^2 B[2] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[2]^3 + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] B[1] B[2] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[2] B[3]^2 == 0, 
   1/4 \[Beta] A[1]^3 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] A[2] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1] A[2]^2 - 9 \[Omega]^2 A[3] + \[Omega]0^2 A[3] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2]^2 A[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[3]^3 - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1] B[1]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[1]^2 - 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] B[1] B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1] B[2] - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1] B[2]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[2]^2 + 
     6 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 B[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[3] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -6 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 A[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[1] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] B[1] - 3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[1] - 
     1/4 \[Beta] B[1]^3 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] B[2] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[1] B[2]^2 - 
     9 \[Omega]^2 B[3] + \[Omega]0^2 B[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[3] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[3]^2 B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[1]^2 B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] B[2]^2 B[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[3]^3 == 0};
```

If I put in some numerical values for the coefficients and solve I get 483 solutions.

```
eqns1 = eqns /. {\[Omega]0 -> 2 \[Pi] 10, \[Zeta] -> 1/100, \[Beta] ->
      5000, F -> 100., \[Omega] -> 2 \[Pi] 12.};
Timing[sol = NSolve[eqns1, uk, Reals];]
```

(* {0.171875, Null} *)

The first 49 solutions are identical except for numerical error.

```
Table[sol[[n]][[All, 2]] - sol[[1]][[All, 2]], {n, 49}] // Chop
```

(*
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
*)

Other groups of solutions are also similarly identical. If I put in alternative values for the coefficients e.g. `\[Omega] -> 2 \[Pi] 14.` I get a different number of solutions. I need to calculate solutions for a range of values of Omega.

`DeleteDuplicates` does not work but anyway I would like to make `NSolve` work without producing duplicates. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a precision problem. Therefore, increase "WorkingPrecision"

Comment: @Nasser well spotted. Bad habit of using `NDSolve` more than `NSolve`. Thanks corrected.

Comment: @DanielHuber Increasing or decreasing `WorkingPrecision` results in "Subsystem could not be solved". Also, takes a long time to reach that conclusion.

Comment: Why not to use `FindRoot`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I tried using `FindRoot`. It needs starting values so I used random ones and then I get a failure due to lack of `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: As a quick experiment, looking at @DanielHuber 's solution I replace `A[0],A[2],B[2]` with zeros, eliminate all decimal points, and then `InputForm[Expand[N[Simplify[Reduce[eqns, uk]]]]]` quickly gives 9 solutions for `A[1]` and `A[3],B[1],B[3]` are each 8th degree polynomials in your choice of `A[1]` Without the `Expand` those polynomials involve coefficients `~=10^200`

Comment: @Hugh Are you looking for an unique solution that depends on a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

For parametric research it could be better to use `FindRoot` as follows

```
uk = {A[0], A[1], B[1], A[2], B[2], A[3], B[3]};
eqns = {\[Omega]0^2 A[0] + \[Beta] A[0]^3 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[1]^2 + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[2]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[3]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[1]^2 - 3/4 \[Beta] A[2] B[1]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[1] B[2] - 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[1] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[2]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[2] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -F - \[Omega]^2 A[1] + \[Omega]0^2 A[1] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 A[1] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^3 + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] A[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2]^2 + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] A[3] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[3]^2 + 
     2 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 B[1] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[1] B[1]^2 - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[3] B[1]^2 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] B[1] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[2]^2 - 3/4 \[Beta] A[3] B[2]^2 + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[1] B[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0] B[2] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[2] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -2 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 A[1] - \[Omega]^2 B[
       1] + \[Omega]0^2 B[1] + 3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 B[1] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[1] - 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] B[1] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[1] - 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[3] B[1] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[3]^2 B[1] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[1]^3 + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[2] - 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[3] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] A[3] B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[1] B[2]^2 + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] B[3] - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[3] - 3/4 \[Beta] B[1]^2 B[3] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] B[2]^2 B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[1] B[3]^2 == 0, 
   3/2 \[Beta] A[0] A[1]^2 - 4 \[Omega]^2 A[2] + \[Omega]0^2 A[2] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 A[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[2] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^3 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] A[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] A[3]^2 - 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[0] B[1]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1]^2 + 
     4 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[1] B[2] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[2] B[2]^2 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] B[1] B[3] - 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] B[2] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -4 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 A[2] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[1] - 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[3] B[1] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2] A[3] B[1] - 
     4 \[Omega]^2 B[2] + \[Omega]0^2 B[2] + 3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[2] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[2] - 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[3] B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3]^2 B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] B[1]^2 B[2] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[2]^3 + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] B[1] B[2] B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[2] B[3]^2 == 0, 
   1/4 \[Beta] A[1]^3 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] A[2] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1] A[2]^2 - 9 \[Omega]^2 A[3] + \[Omega]0^2 A[3] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 A[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 A[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[2]^2 A[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[3]^3 - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1] B[1]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[1]^2 - 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] B[1] B[2] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2] B[1] B[2] - 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[1] B[2]^2 + 3/2 \[Beta] A[3] B[2]^2 + 
     6 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 B[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[3] B[3]^2 == 
    0, -6 \[Zeta] \[Omega] \[Omega]0 A[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[1] + 
     3 \[Beta] A[0] A[2] B[1] - 3/4 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[1] - 
     1/4 \[Beta] B[1]^3 + 3 \[Beta] A[0] A[1] B[2] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1] A[2] B[2] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[1] B[2]^2 - 
     9 \[Omega]^2 B[3] + \[Omega]0^2 B[3] + 3 \[Beta] A[0]^2 B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] A[1]^2 B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] A[2]^2 B[3] + 
     3/4 \[Beta] A[3]^2 B[3] + 3/2 \[Beta] B[1]^2 B[3] + 
     3/2 \[Beta] B[2]^2 B[3] + 3/4 \[Beta] B[3]^3 == 0};

eqns1 = eqns /. {\[Omega]0 -> 2 \[Pi] 10, \[Zeta] -> 1/100, \[Beta] ->
      5000, F -> 100., \[Omega] -> 2 \[Pi] 12.};

sols[1] = FindRoot[eqns1, Table[{uk[[i]], .1}, {i, Length[uk]}]]

X = Range[2 Pi 12, 2 Pi 13.5, .1]; nn = Length[X] - 1;

Do[sols[n + 1] = 
   FindRoot[
    eqns /. {\[Omega]0 -> 2 \[Pi] 10, \[Zeta] -> 1/100, \[Beta] -> 
       5000, F -> 100., \[Omega] -> X[[n + 1]]}, 
    Table[{uk[[i]], uk[[i]] /. sols[n]}, {i, Length[uk]}], 
    MaxIterations -> 1000, 
    Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}];, {n, nn}]
```

Visualization

```
Table[ListPlot[Transpose[{X, Table[uk[[j]] /. sols[i], {i, nn + 1}]}],
   PlotLabel -> uk[[j]], AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", ""}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], {j, Length[uk]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1.**
We can select the most likely solutions using `NMinimize` as follows

```
f = eqns[[All, 1]] /. {\[Omega]0 -> 2 \[Pi] 10, \[Zeta] -> 
     1/100, \[Beta] -> 5000, F -> 100, \[Omega] -> y};
X = Range[2 Pi 10, 2 Pi 20, .1]; sol = 
 Table[NMinimize[f . f , uk] // Quiet, {y, X}];
```

To select a solution, we use criteria

```
dsol = Transpose[{sol[[All, 1]], X, sol[[All, 2, All, 2]]}]

sdsol = Select[dsol, #[[1]] <= 10^-12 &];
```

Visualization

```
Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose[{sdsol[[All, 2]], sdsol[[All, 3, i]]}], 
  PlotLabel -> uk[[i]], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  Frame -> True], {i, Length[uk]}]
```

[image: Figure 2]
Note that this is another branch of the solution, not similar to the first.

Comment: This is very helpful. Works well for some values but `FindRoot` runs out of precision for larger values of your X. However, better than `NSolve`.

Comment: @Hugh At `X>13.5` we can try smaller step like 0.01.

Comment: I just tried smaller steps. No help. Pity.

Comment: @Hugh We can select the most likely solutions using `NMinimize`. See Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting WorkingPrecision->20, it then takes 85 sec. and gives only 3 solutions, although it gives a warning that the input is less precise than working precision:

```
Timing[sol = NSolve[eqns1, uk, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20];]
sol
```

{85.8125, Null}

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's a big working precision. I did not try that large. However, the time of solution is now a problem.  Also, finding the required precision. Do you know if we can do something to condition the equations beforehand so that multiple solutions are not present?

Comment: Things to try:  FullSimplify of the equations before solving. Solve the first equation for B[3] and replace it in the rest of equations, then scond equation for B[2].. Note also, If you work with machine precision, WorkingPrecision is 16, therefore a value of 20 is no very large.

Answer (score 1):

With the OP's `sol`, we can gather the similar solutions together, find their mean, and if desired, polish them up with `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[eqns1, Transpose@{uk, #}] & /@ 
 Mean /@ FindClusters[uk /. sol]
(*
{{A[0] -> 0., 
  A[1] -> 0.522588, B[1] -> 0.46034, A[2] -> 0., 
  B[2] -> 0., A[3] -> -0.00538341, B[3] -> 0.00805524},
 {A[0] -> 0., 
  A[1] -> -0.512465, B[1] -> 0.404015, A[2] -> 0., B[2] -> 0., 
  A[3] -> 0.00335023, B[3] -> 0.00714414},
 {A[0] -> 0., 
  A[1] -> -0.0578141, B[1] -> 0.00317649, A[2] -> 0., B[2] -> 0., 
  A[3] -> -5.06698*10^-6, B[3] -> 8.73366*10^-7}}
*)
```

Comment: Could be an approach. Any idea if it is mathematically valid? Do sum of errors typically have zero mean?  Thanks

Comment: @Hugh Depends on the distribution of errors and if they are random. If the distribution mean is zero, the expected value of the mean would be zero. And the standard deviation would be smaller. If the errors are systematic or biased, then no. But honestly, I wouldn't worry about that. Polishing with `FindRoot` is the cure. `NSolve` usually produces pretty good candidates for all the solutions. If the problem is ill-conditioned, use `FindRoot` with a high `WorkingPrecision`.  If using `FindRoot`, then initializing with the first solution in each cluster is probably just as good as the mean